# Views dimensions as percentage

Tags: ios, view

I need to set the position of the buttons, labels and views depending on the device resolution.
How can i set buttons and another views dimensions as percentage in the Interface builder ?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you want to do, because 'device resolution' is almost never the way to go. Since the retina display every thing is in point now.

Comment: For example, I have two pickers, one of them with 2 components. I want the big to fit the 80% of the screen, and the other one the other 20%. If i put the width as pixels, in some resolutions the little picker will be too big, or too small... I need percentage!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Maybe there's another way to accomplish what you want, so you should elaborate on what it is that you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: For example, I have a row of buttons, I want them all to have the same width

Comment: @Fischer, you can do that with layout constraints. If you don't know how to use those, you should look at the videos (there are 3 different ones I think) from the WWDC 2012 meeting. Those can be found on the Mac Dev Center site.

Comment: Ups, but layout constraints is only compatible with ios 6, i want compatibility with ios 5

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 2 elements, Normal "Springs and Struct" should be enough in IB.
They exactly match the `UIViewAutoresizing` that are set on a `UIView`.

If it's not enough you will have to use `IBOutlet` and calculate their size and position in your `viewDidLoad` method using the "bounds.size" of their super view.

---

`[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]` will return you the size of the screen in `point`.
It will give you the frame or your application root view in Screen coordinate system. So if you have a status bar your origin will be (0, 20).

But Again you should check the size of the super view inside which you are placing your element to determine the positioning of your element.
`myView.superView.bounds.size.height * 0.8;`

If you really really really want to know the resolution in pixel of the screen you are on (which is a very very very bad idea) a UIView have a property call `contentScaleFactor`, but unless you are doing some very low level drawing you should never concern yourself with this.

Comment: I have tried and have some problems getting the devices resolution.

Comment: float screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
     float screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

Comment: This method doesn't give me the real resolution of the device